# Guy as anchorage tool

Tags: terminology

What does "guy" refers to in case of anchorage of a steel structure to a wall ? *"..in addition to tie-ins, a series of guys shall be installed.."

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to our site. You may not realise that we expect our users to do their research before asking a question here. Check out [guy - definition 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guy). If this doesn't resolve your question, please [edit] your post to explain what you've found and what you need explained. For further guidance, see [ask], and I also recommend taking the quick **[Tour]** of our site :-)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions, Chappo, in fact it was the first time I was using the site ! I'll take care next time :-) Stefano

Answer (score 2):

The term is *guy rope*.

> **guy(2)** *noun*
> A rope or line fixed to the ground to secure a tent or other structure.
> ‘A guy rope had come loose and it was at the mercy of the wind.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guy)
>
> A **guy rope** is a rope or wire that has one end fastened to a tent or pole and the other end fixed to the ground, so that it keeps the tent or pole in position.
> [- Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/guy-rope)